# open bootstrap modal programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have the following modal in boostrap

```
 <div
        className="modal fade"
        id="exampleModal"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
        aria-hidden="true"
      >
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">
                Select a wallet
              </h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
</div>
</div>
```

and I got a `a` element that when clicking, shows the modal.

```
<a
                    className="nav-link wallet-btn"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal"
                    data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
                  >
                    Show Modal
                  </a>
```

If I want to close the button programatically, i do the following:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.btn-close');
    if(el) {
      // @ts-ignore
      el.click();
    }
```

How can I open this modal programatically by following the same idea/way ?

Comment: reference he modal and call show like the documentation says to do?

Comment: Are you not using [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)?

Comment: not using react-bootstrap unfortunatelly. using plain bootstrap. any code reference ideas ?

Comment: not using jquery as well. so need something like document.querySelector solution

Comment: Bootstrap 4 _requires_ jQuery. How is that not available?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bootstrap method `.show()`.

```js
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal")

if (modal) {
  modal.addEventListener("click", function() {
    modal.show()
  })
}
```

For more refer to docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#show